# Spring 6 and spring-batch migration cause some autowired not working anymore

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to migrate from spring 5 to 6 and spring-batch 4 to 5 but some @automwired not workind anymore.

I'm trying to create a step like this:

```
@Bean
public Step fileBrowseMultiThreadStep(JobRepository jobRepository,
  PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, 
  ItemProcessor<? super ApiDTO, ? extends ApiDTO> itemProcessorSelector) {
     return new StepBuilder("File read and save in database", jobRepository).chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager).reader(...).processor(itemProcessorSelector).writer(...).build();
}
```

before migration all work fine but now when i'm starting my application i got:

```
Error creating bean with name 'fileBrowseMultiThreadStep' defined in class path resource [...BatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'fileBrowseMultiThreadStep' parameter 3: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor<fr.test.dto.ApiDTO, fr.test.dto.ApiDTO>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

My itemProcessorSelector is a StepScope bean declare like this:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemProcessor<? extends ApiDTO, ? extends ApiDTO> itemProcessorSelector(
  JobBeanProvider jobBeanProviderForThisJob) {
   return jobBeanProviderForThisJob.itemProcessor();
}
```

my JobBeanProvider interface has this method to ovveride:

```
 ItemProcessor<? extends ApiDTO, ? extends ApiDTO> itemProcessor();
```

The first thing i can see is with the keyword `super`, my fileBrowseMultiThreadStep take `itemProcessorSelector` with `ItemProcessor<? super ApiDTO, ? extends ApiDTO>` but my JobBeanProvider declare `ItemProcessor<? extends ApiDTO, ? extends ApiDTO>`
I try to change to `ItemProcessor<? super ApiDTO, ? extends ApiDTO>`

But now my declaration :

```
  @Override
  public ItemProcessor<ActivityApiDTO, ActivityApiDTO> itemProcessor() {
     return activityProcessor;
  }
```

failed to compil because ActivityApiDTO is not super ApiDto that i understand...

I can't change the delcaration of the method `fileBrowseMultiThreadStep` because spring-batch process method take super and extend object so i need super and extend...

```
  public SimpleStepBuilder<I, O> processor(ItemProcessor<? super I, ? extends O> processor) {
    this.processor = processor;
    return this;
}
```

Spring 6 seems to be more restrictive with autowired but does it possible to configure it to work like before? or if someone can help me?

#EDIT1

I have try to simply cast the processor call with:

```
.processor((ItemProcessor<? super ApiDTO, ? extends ApiDTO>)itemProcessorSelector)
```

and for now it compil and start... i try to check if all job work like before...

thanks

Comment: `and for now it compil and start... i try to check if all job work like before...`: do you still have the issue?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine no i will test next week and close this question if all work fine